# How to get a most recent jobs in ATOMIC AE REST API?

Tags: api, automic

I'm trying to pull the job details from the Automic server using the below API.

http://server:8088/ae/api/v1/800/executions/?name=*name*&type=JOBS

This query just sends me the data for job executions only in the past 24 hours. The executions in the previous runs are not returned. How do I get the latest execution that happened even if it was two weeks back?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this?
https://docs.automic.com/documentation/webhelp/english/AA/21/DOCU/21/Automic%20Automation%20Guides/Content/REST_API/AE_REST_API_General_FilterExecutionList.htm

include_deactivated could be involved